# UISplitViewController - Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller, ios8, uiappearance

I am using the new UISplitViewController for ios8 that has preferred display modes. My master split view is a UITabBarController with a UINavigationController inside it. I disabled the `presentsWithSwipe` gesture, and instead have a button in my detail view controller that toggles the splitviewcontroller between 2 preferred display mode states: UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible and UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden.

When I toggle the button so that both view controllers are visible, I can see my navigation controller display it's tableview controller. However, when I click on a cell in my tableviewcontroller that performs a storyboard segue to another view controller, I get the following error:

`Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <ReferenceTableViewController: 0x7fde50540d50>`

My set up is

SplitMasterViewController --> UITabBarController --> UINavigationController --> ReferenceTableViewController --> ReferenceDetailViewController

SplitDetailViewController --> UINavigationController --> MainViewController

Basically, I want to animate in/out the master view controller which provides information relevant to the MainViewController. Actions taken in the MasterViewController do not replace out the DetailViewController, but rather should navigate within the MasterViewController frame. Kind of like having an iPhone side by side with a smaller iPad, with independent content in each.

However, I'm not getting any of the view appearance methods being called in the ReferenceTableViewController or the RefernenceDetailViewController. I always call super if I override any appearance methods, so I'm not sure where the error is coming from. Any ideas?

Comment: No answer, but as I am seeing this too, I thought I would add to the available information. This is an iPad app. I too have disabled presentsWithSwipe and am using a button to show the primary view controller. In my case I swap from UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden to UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay when in portrait mode. I only get this log message the first time I do this after rotating to portrait mode.

Comment: I was getting this warning too, I changed a bunch of my layout code to work with the iPhone as well as the iPad and managed to clear out this warning in the process. It's hard to pinpoint exactly what did it but I was modifying things according to this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25896529/1304462).  Hopefully that will help you with an idea of where to look.